# WCF, MVC4 and authentication : customizing error

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to custom the "default authentication" that is provided by Visal Studio project.
I've a database with some users inside that is linked to my project. What I want to do : ensure that login/password couple is in the database and so connect user.

Just to give you ideas of what have been done :
AccountController :

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
 {
    try
    {
        var context = new MyService.MyEntities2(new Uri("http://localhost:12345/MyWS.svc/"));
        var usr = from user in context.PERSON
                  where user.LOGIN == model.UserName && user.PASSWORD == model.Password
                  select user;
        List<MyWebPortal.MyService.PERSON> lpers = usr.ToList();
        int nbRes = lpers.Count();
        if (ModelState.IsValid && nbRes ==1)
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Erreur : "+ex.ToString());
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Authentication error");
    return View(model);
}
```

LoginModel :

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Login form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

But i've got the following error :

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de cette requête. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code></code><message xml:lang="fr-FR">Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de cette requête.</message></error> 
à System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery(DataServiceContext context) 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) 
--- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne --- 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute() 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator() 
à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) 
à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
à MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model, String returnUrl) dans d:\....\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProg\MyWS\Controllers\AccountController.cs:ligne 45
```

Where ligne 45 is

```
List<MyWebPortal.MyService.PERSON> lpers = usr.ToList();
```

Did I do something wrong with the request ? Thanks !

Comment: Please translate error messages to English before posting questions to SO.

Comment: Translation : "An error as occured while processing the request". Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's working now. What I did : I just add this line :

```
var context = new SteelcaseService.SteelcaseEntities2(new Uri("http://localhost:12345/Steelcase.svc/"));
----> var persons = context.PERSON.ToList();
var usr = from user in persons
          where user.LOGIN == model.UserName && user.PASSWORD == model.Password
          select user;
```

Could you please, please explain why ? Because that's not the first time I use that trick and I dunno why it's changing anything. And in the mean time, I don't think it's a good idea if I have a lot of information to recover.

Comment: You are passing entire `LoginModel` to Entity Framework which cannot be translated to SQL. Copy username and password to local variables and use those in your LINQ query. Also consider not storing password as plain text in DB but use at least a hash of the salted password (i.e. MD5(password + "some salt, like user id"))